# How to get files and folders from a path in k6?

Tags: k6

How to get the list of files and folders from a path? And is it possible to apply RegEx when searching?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? What is your use-case? I don't think it is possible, but this question is lacking detail to be answered properly.

Comment: @knittl as straight-forward as wanting to check a directory for certain format of filenames. Will use those files for testing out different payloads as actual scenarios for integration/business rules testing instead of just load-testing.

Comment: This sounds like something that should be done outside of k6. k6 will only execute a single script file and does not have builtin support to scan your local file system.

Answer (score 0):

By default, you can't reach the filesystem from k6 scripts, this is because of design choice (security). If those files are js files, you can import them or bundle them with a webpack.

If you really need to read files you can write a [k6 extension](https://k6.io/docs/extensions/). For example [xk6-file](https://github.com/avitalique/xk6-file) is k6 extension for *writing* to files. You can start with this.

Answer (score 0):

The way I've solved this is:

1. Having a list of files to read. I coded an script (python in my case) that will read the directory with the files I want to use and create a json file containing an array of files: `["file1.ext", "file2.ext", "fileN.ext"]
2. In the test, I used k6's [`SharedArray`](https://k6.io/docs/javascript-api/k6-data/sharedarray/#example) for obtaining the previous list, iterate it, and create a final array with the content of all previous files.

The code looks pretty similar to this:

```
const data = new SharedArray('reqs', function () {
  const file = open('/requests_list.json');
  const list = JSON.parse(file);

  const requests = [];

  list.forEach(filePath => {
    requests.push(open(`/requests/${filePath}`))
  });

  return requests;
});

export default function () {
  const body = data[Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length)];
  const res = http.post(url, body, params);
  check(res, { 'status was 200': (r) => r.status == 200 });
  sleep(1);
}
```

Another option I thought (but haven't implemented) is to use [xk6 exec extension](https://github.com/grafana/xk6-exec) for through bash obtain the list and process it. The benefit of this is that you don't require an external script for creating the list file.